How to compile XLA PJRT plugin for Darwin?
I'm trying to compile the XLA CPU plugin for Darwin (specifically a Macbook). It's building but I'm not getting a valid file type out. I'm running
./configure.py --backend=CPU --os=DARWIN
bazel build //xla/pjrt/c:pjrt_c_api_cpu_plugin.so

in a tensorflow/build:latest-python3.9 docker container, as recommended, but I'm getting a .so file out, and even if I rename it to .dylib I'm seeing
not a mach-o file

when I try to use it.

I used a more recent XLA commit. I'm not sure which commit I was using in the question (perhaps 79d745f5873c0c93bcb43b25436c212da1f2b997), but I upgraded to 361ffafd01d30da52f03d9d02bc873dad0d4e647.
I then built directly on the mac, without Docker. I guess I was not cross-compiling for Darwin. I'm not sure cross-compilation is even possible. I installed Bazelisk, then in the openxla/xla repo root, ran
./configure.py --backend=CPU --os=darwin
bazel build //xla/pjrt/c:pjrt_c_api_cpu_plugin.so

Finally, I replaced the .so extension on the build artifact with .dylib.
Note I used my own (extensive but not exhaustive) test suite, rather than that of XLA, and I'm not using a Python frontend such as JAX.

I've built it on my macOS (no docker). The build is working fine just with the clang version 15 (at the moment).
Here's how I've done.
https://medium.com/@davideraffaele.marro/how-to-handle-pjrt-on-a-mac-mx-arm-26d16a0c9bd9

thanks, though from an SO perspective, hyperlinks are not good because they can go dead. I recommend copy-pasting what's relevant here

running directly on mac was enough. The other instructions were unnecessary for me
